# Using Dumper not triggering a failure

Tags: perl, strict, data-dumper

when running code like this:

```
use strict;
print Dumper "something";
```

nothing is printed out and no error occurs during compile and runtime. Why does this happen? Why doesn't `strict` prevent this code from running? Why is there no error at runtime, even though Dumper is unknown?

I know it produces a warning when those are explicitly enabled, but I'm interested why is this code considered "correct" in any way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does defined sdf return true in this Perl example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646997/why-does-defined-sdf-return-true-in-this-perl-example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the valid syntaxes for `print` is

```
print FILEHANDLE LIST
```

In your program Perl is treating `Dumper` as a filehandle glob.

Running this code with warnings enabled will tell you:

`print() on unopened filehandle Dumper at ...`

Comment: Ok - I see that now. Do you know the specific reason why actions on unopened filehandles are not errors by default?

Comment: @viraptor: Because you didn’t use my boilderplate. It’s because Unix never says *“please”,* and it never says *“I’m sorry.”*

Comment: @viraptor: they *are* errors; print will return false indicating that it failed.  They are also warnings, since they indicate a probable coding error.  *Enabling warnings is more important than using strict.*  They are *not* exceptions (though you can promote errors in all or selected built ins to be exceptions using `autodie`).

Comment: Also, had you done "print Dumper("something");"  it would have failed correctly.  The correct way is "print &Dumper("something");", though most people don't prefer this method.  And I agree with ysth, I always use the shebash line #!/usr/bin/perl -w

Comment: @Jeremy: Prefixing sub calls with `&` is generally considered to be a relic of Perl 4 and treated as more-or-less deprecated. Why do you claim `print &Dumper(...)` to be more correct than `print Dumper(...)`? `Also, `use warnings` tends to be preferred over `perl -w` these days, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: print FILEHANDLE LIST isn't a print-specific syntax, it's indirect object syntax: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax

Answer (score 11):

If you had begun with the standard boilerplate, then you would know:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# name_of_program - what the program does as brief one-liner
#
# Your Name <your_email@your_host.TLA>
# Date program written/released
#################################################################

use 5.10.0;

use utf8;
use strict;
use autodie;
use warnings FATAL => "all";

#  ⚠ change to agree with your input: ↓
use open ":std" => IN    => ":encoding(ISO-8859-1)",
                   OUT   => ":utf8";
#  ⚠ change for your output: ↑ — *maybe*, but leaving as UTF-8 is sometimes better

END {close STDOUT}

our $VERSION = 1.0;

$| = 1;
```

The answer is that your program is syntactically but not semantically correct.  You are printing `"something"` to the unopened `Dumper` filehandle-object, because `Dumper` is in the dative slot for the `print` method call.  That makes `Dumper` `print`’s invocant.  But you never opened a handle by that name, so you are printing to an uninitialized filehandle.

Use my boilerplate.  **PLEASE!**

Comment: @friedo: to make sure it autodies on a failure to flush and close stdout.  Disk full.  I/O error.  Stuff like that.

Comment: Setting autoflush ($|) by default is not a good practice.  It sometimes makes sense, but not always, and should not be done in a boilerplate. At the very least, the boilerplate should have a comment indicating that it is optional.