# Perl if not working?

Tags: perl, comparison, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

sub start
{
    ...
}

sub stop
{
    ...
}

if (defined $ARGV[0])
{
    if ($ARGV[0]=='start') {start}
    elsif ($ARGV[0]=='stop') {stop}
    else {die "Unrecognized command: $ARGV[0]"}
}
```

Whatever I do though, it always executes `&start`. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Linux Mint 10 and Perl 5.10.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're using numeric comparison to check string equality, which converts the arguments to numbers first before comparing them.

In this case, 'start' is not a number, so it gets converted to `0`; the value in `$ARGV[0]` (which is expected to be a word here) is also converted, resulting in another `0` and a final condition of `if (0 == 0)`, which is always true.

You want to use the `eq` string-wise comparison operator instead:

```
if ($ARGV[0] eq 'start') { start }
```

See the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Relational-Operators) for more information on the different comparison operators.

Note that (as has been pointed out in the comments) including `use warnings;` at the top of your script would have caused `perl` to warn you about this from the start. Always including `use warnings;` and `use strict;` is generally best practice, as it helps catch these kinds of errors early.

Comment: Treated as a number, 'start' is the same as 0, and so are most other strings.  Using `use warnings; use strict;` would help.

Comment: Indeed, with strict and warnings turned on, the problem would pop out right away with a relevant warning message.

Comment: you should add that his first condition is actually `if ( 0==0 )` which is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @Axeman: I'll add it in my answer, but Jonathan's comment speaks for itself

Comment: @Jonathan: +1. Adding to your comment: A string starting with a number (like `'1234abc'`) would be converted to that number (`1234`), and anything else is converted to `0`

Answer (score 2):

The bug is that your program neglected to start with [the standard boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272816/using-dumper-not-triggering-a-failure/4272858#4272858) for Perl code.

Comment: The bug is using Perl in the first place. I always thought Perl was a write only language. The question teaches me otherwise...